# Where is the 'start' file generated by 'play dist'

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have a scala play web application, I run

```
play dist
```

and it shows

```
[info] Done packaging.  
[info]   
[info] Your package is ready in /home/enzo/workspace/scn-pic/srv/target/universal/scn-pic-srv-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip  
[info]
```

I unzip the SNAPSHOT.zip but there's no start file in it, as documented [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.2/ProductionDist).

My scala play version is `play 2.2.1 built with Scala 2.10.2` and my system is Archlinux.

Where is the start file located?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be a script file named "scn-pic-srv" in the "bin" folder.